# Best way to deploy code and restore database in a managed Application on Azure MarketPlace

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-marketplace

Our goal is publishing our offer to Azure MarketPlace. We created an ARM template for our infrastructure and had no issues with that.

Our main issue is how to deploy our code and DB schema through the purchase process.

Microsoft recommends Deployment Scripts so we made ours which contains, CLI commands to restore a .BACPAC sql file, app settings configurations and a CURL command for zip deployment via KUDU for the web application.

.BACPAC and zip package for code are in blob storage.

If we run our scripts in a custom ARM template deployment in Azure, they work fine !!

But when we run them through the marketplace purchase, they fail with no error logs.

Down below you can find our script commands.

```
"scriptContent": "
      az sql db import -s $sqlserver -n $sqldatabase -g $rg -p $sqlpassword -u $sqlusername --storage-key $sqlstoragekey --storage-key-type $storagekeytype --storage-uri $storageuri \r\n
      az webapp deployment user set --user-name $deploymentUser --password $deploymentPass \r\n
      az webapp config connection-string set --name $applicationName --resource-group $rg --settings DefaultConnection=\"Server=tcp:$sqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=$sqldatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=$sqlusername;Password=$sqlpassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;\" --connection-string-type SQLAzure \r\n
      az webapp config appsettings set --name $applicationName --resource-group $rg --settings PortalUrl=\https://$applicationName.azurewebsites.net/\ \r\n
      az webapp config appsettings set --name $applicationName --resource-group $rg --settings AzureAd:Domain=\"$AADDomain\" \r\n
      az webapp config appsettings set --name $applicationName --resource-group $rg --settings AzureAd:ClientId=\"$AADClientId\" \r\n
      az webapp config appsettings set --name $applicationName --resource-group $rg --settings AzureAd:TenantId=\"$AADTenantId\" \r\n
      az webapp config appsettings set --name $applicationName --resource-group $rg --settings AzureAd:ClientSecret=\"$AADClientSecret\" \r\n
      az webapp restart --name $applicationName --resource-group $rg \r\n
      curl -X PUT -u $deploymentUser:$deploymentPass https://$applicationName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d \"{'packageUri':'$applicationUri$applicationStorageKey'}\" \r\n
      ",
```

In case our approach is wrong, any example, documentation and suggestions will be super helpful.

Feel free to ask for more information if any.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to do a separate database restore or code deployment to see exactly where the error occurred?

Comment: Hello Jane. Before we create our ARM template, we run each CLI command separately for testing/debugging reasons. Via Template deployment in Azure, we managed to successfully create the resources and run these scripts.
In marketplace purchase process, we couldn’t make it.
During debugging, we tried to run only some commands such as “az webapp config connection-string set” with the values we wanted, just to see if these commands will work and we took SubscriptionNotFound error. The subscription id of the client is matching the ARM’s template.
Any thoughts?